# Unity doesn't handle Compiz Window Previews. Should I file a bug report?

Tags: unity, compiz, panel

If I turn on Window Previews in Compiz, the top panel disappears in Unity. If I turn the feature off, the panel doesn't come back normally only after restarting the session. I guess it should be filed as a bug, but the ubuntu-bug unity told me to ask it here first and I didn't want to bypass this step :) So what should I do now?

UPDATE: I filed a bug report @launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/776445

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File a bug ;). I've encountered problems too but I wasn't sure if it was only me :).
When you file the bug edit your question and add a link to it btw.

Comment: done, filed the bug :)

Comment: @r1pp3rj4ck: cool ^^ - remember to mark this question answered btw. (click the tick on my answer if it answered for you).